# Create cryptographically secure passwords. And verify that it works

Tags: c++, security, random, cryptography, passwords

I am working on a software that also generates passwords. It does it basically this way:

```
static char AllowedChars[] = {...}
static int passwordLength = 123;

std::string password;

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, sizeof(AllowedChars) - 1);
for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; ++i) {
    int index = dist(mt);
    password.push_back(AllowedChars[index]);
}
```

**How can I know, that this algorithm creates cryptographically secure passwords?**

I know that `random_device` is dependent on the compiler, target platform, its own version, etc. I also cannot rely on the output of methods like  `std::random_device::entropy`, since it *may* be just a fixed value. See: http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpps-random_device.html

I also cannot do black box testing of its output: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83254/how-to-check-randomness-of-random-number-generators

**How can I *know* which "source of randomness" (i.e. which RNG) is used? And if the seed has enough entropy?** (Obviously, this must be done on the compiled binary, since static source code cannot reveal these details.)
With this output I could verify that a CSPRNG is used.

Comment: If you want to create passwords like _this_, why not just use a hash digest? SHA-3 has the possibility to output digests as long as you'd like.

Comment: Since mt19937 is *not* cryptographically secure I'd be automatically suspicious about using it.

Comment: also note that the [MT isn't even a very good PRNG](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50059), there are algorithms that have a smaller state space and code size, are both faster to initialise and sample from, and produce statistically "better" output

Comment: At least `std::mt19937` [is well-defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) in C++. But Mersenne Twister is not cryptographically secure (as one of the answers says), and this is true regardless of how `random_device` is ultimately implemented in the "compiled binary" (whether as a cryptographic RNG or otherwise) or what "source of entropy" it ultimately uses.

Answer (score 10):

A `Mersenne Twister` based [pseudorandom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) number generator is **not** cryptographically secure.

The reason a MT isn't good for crypto purposes is because given some set of outputs you can start making **accurate** predictions on the next output.

Cryptographically secure requires all primitives and the underlying protocol to be cryptographically sound without sacrificing entropy or uniformity.

**Uniformity** is really important, not just that passwords are 'random' but also uniform.

For example, a shared secret (agreed elliptic curve point, prior to hashing) after ECDHE may well be a random secret, but it certainly isn't uniform!

The best way I've seen this put is from [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27593/hashing-a-diffie-hellman-result) answer:

*"the result of the DH key exchange is a **group element** that is **computationally indistinguishable** from a random/**uniformly distributed element in the group**. **However**, what is important to note is that **a uniformly distributed group element is not (read: necessarily) a uniformly distributed string** (where the latter must have each bit equal 0 with probability 1/2 and equal 1 with probability 1/2)"*

So to answer your question more directly, if you want to build a password generator I would just encode a byte array from a `CSPRNG` such as `/dev/(u)random` or an onboard `TRNG` to hexadecimals rather than building a special password string. Remember the precise format of the hexadecimals (separator characters, upper- or lowercase) if you do.

If you're using `C`, why not just use `libsodium` to [generate](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/generating_random_data) random bytes, it's elegant and secure.

Comment: "For example, a shared secret (agreed elliptic curve point, prior to hashing) after ECDHE may well be a random secret, but it certainly isn't uniform!" Really? Maybe in theory, but [read this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48047/can-a-raw-ecdh-shared-secret-be-used-directly-for-encryption) to see that you are wrong in practice.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I suggest taking the hex representation of the binary data so it's a printable usable password Re: ./dev/urandom generates binary data, why should you dump "hex" data? – Maarten Bodewes 3 mins ago

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203544/discussion-between-woodstock-and-maarten-bodewes).

Answer (score 5):

Probably not, as the Mersenne twister algorithm is insecure and the state of the algorithm can likely be determined, especially if enough output is available. Unfortunately, the `passwordLength` integer is set to 123 - way too high. So this may leak information. Instead, you could try using [`std:random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/random_device) *directly* rather than `mt19937`. There is no specific need for special libraries, it seems to me. However, you must make sure that your version of `std:random_device` is secure (as part of hardening your std: library in general).

The principle to use of a uniform range to pick a password character from an alphabet - as shown in the code - should be considered correct. To have an idea about the likely strength of the passwords, you can take the 2-log of the amount of valid characters, and then multiply it with the amount of characters in the password. Good passwords should have a strength of at least 48 to 64 bits, great ones should be above 64. Of course with the above algorithm there is no check if you've generated a weak password by chance, so you cannot be perfectly sure. Having a large enough password should take care of that though. Generally you can assume a max of 6.6 bits per character if you allow *all* ASCII printable characters, so 10-12 characters should do fine. For hexadecimals you would of course expect 4 bits per character, for base 64 6 bits per character.

Beware that many systems have stupid requirements for passwords that make this scheme too simple. The system may require specific amount of special characters or digits. Limits on password length is often also an issue.

---

I think that using a random number device that is guaranteed to use the system's RNG is paramount to security. You may want to try another random number generator that does this, but unfortunately, with many compilation options in many libraries, in the end you must make sure yourself I suppose.

Creating your own `uniform_random_bit_generator` (to replace `mt19937` and `random_device` would be one way of doing that, so you can use the other `std:` functionality that hinges on it. That interface is only specified in C++ 20 though, so yeah, getting there.

Comment: Good answer. I had an after thought, well two! Given that we can’t know the entropy of a string (as it may be posted elsewhere reducing entropy or be a hash of a weak password etc) is there really value in calculating “theoretical” entropy with log2?

Comment: Secondly, and we spoke about this before, I completely accept character encoding is just about the representation of the bits, not the actual value of the bits. The entropy is present in the value of the bits, however if data with entropy of 128bits is read from /dev/random, encoded with hex and then used in a system with Unicode passwords, doesn’t this kinda stretch the entropy because an attacked doesn’t know you used hex and will have to try all ascii chars for each char of hex anyway. (Even though I accept theoretical entropy is the same)

Comment: @Woodstock: Where Maarten is discussing entropy here, he's talking about the process for generating these strings rather than the entropy of a single string. And it's a very important measure because it provides an upper bound on the work an attacker has to do to guess the password.

Comment: @Woodstock: Your point about encoding has some validity, but from a security analysis perspective it's important to assess the security under the assumption that the attacker can discover most or all "constant" non-secret information. Since the encoding method must be present in both the encrypt and decrypt software it can be discovered for "free".

Comment: @Woodstock: Your welcome. It's interesting to consider the types of attackers when measuring entropy. Most password "attackers" are just bots which use a password model that your encoding method would defeat. So in that case (the most common), your encode-to-hex method actually increases the entropy significantly, because the bot has no clue you've done that. But for well-resourced attackers that are targeting you specifically, they'll work hard and reverse-engineer your software and so on to learn as much info as possible.